# Can I add your names to my book?

Tags: support

I would like to thank the following people for their expert opinions. I would also like to include a name-surname or a nickname if they allow it in my amateur radio test book. If you forget names you can add. Allow = (1). No Allow = (0). Or you can e-mail me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\begin{document}

AboAmmar
Alan Munn
albert
Ambika Vanchinathan
AndréC
Andrew
barbara beeton
Bernard
bmv
Brent.Longborough
CarLaTeX
cfr
Cragfelt
David Carlisle
David Purton
egreg
Enthusiastic Engineer
esdd
ferahfeza
Frédéric
Gonzalo Medina
Heiko Oberdiek
Henri Menke
Ignasi
Jasper Habicht
jknappen
John Kormylo
Joseph Wright
karlkoeller
koleygr
leandriis
Mensch
michal.h21
Mico
Mike
moewe
naphaneal
nickie
Nico Boni
percusse
Phelype Oleinik
Przemysław Scherwentke
Raaja
Richard
Rmano
Robert Fuster
Sandy G
Scz
ShreevatsaR
Sigur
Skillmon
Stephen
Steven B. Segletes
Symbol 1
Thomas F. Sturm
Torbjørn T.
Troy
Ulrich Diez
Ulrike Fischer
@samcarter
Werner
Willie Wong
wipet
Zarko
@Harish Kumar
@Herbert
@ChristianHupfer

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1. Thank you Mr. Özgür.

Comment: 1. You're allowed to add my nickname, thanks.

Comment: 1. You are allowed to use my name, and thanks :)

Comment: 1. you can use my name.

Comment: 1. Sure thing...!

Comment: 1. Yes, you can :-)

Comment: 1. Of course! And thank you for the acknowledgement.

Comment: 1. You can use my nickname.

Comment: My book is published. All permitted names above are written under the "Structural interpretation for books" tab. Permissions after this edition will be included in the other edition. http://www.ym3km.org/kitap

Comment: :( I saw this just now, would have been 1. Good to hear that you got your book done :)

Comment: To cite Skillmon: " :( I saw this just now, would have been 1. Good to hear that you got your book done :) ".