# Is what I want to do right?

Tags: discussion

I would like to thank the following people for their expert opinions. I would also like to include a first name or a nickname if they allow it in my amateur radio test book. Allow = (1). No Allow = (0). Or you can e-mail me.

I want to write down the list of names if what I want is right. If not, I will delete this topic

Comment: Can you make this a bit clearer?

Comment: I wrote a book on amateur radio. I want to write their names in the introduction of my book in order to thank the people who answered my questions on this site. I will write the name or nickname as a list.

Comment: This would be better in Meta.

Comment: It is okay. Is it possible to paste a link to me? I don't want to make a mistake.

Comment: I added. I'm going to erase the topic here in a little while.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question [Can I add your names to my book?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8411) that was already here in the meta thread.  You might want to reword that question a bit -- the characterization of your book is more prominent as phrased here, although it's still a bit sparse.